# Mounting Silex routes, help needed

Tags: php, routes, silex

I register the following routes like this:

```
$app->register(new HomeServiceProvider());
$app->register(new UserServiceProvider());

$app->mount('/', new HomeControllerProvider());
$app->mount('/', new UserControllerProvider());
```

Both controllers have a function like this:

```
$controllers->get("/", 'home.controller:index')
    ->bind('homepage');

$controllers->get("/", 'user.controller:collection')
    ->bind('users');
```

And I can see the home page when I go to following url:

```
/Testing/demo/web/index.php
```

QUESTION:

How do you modify this so that the only routes in the system are:

```
/Testing/demo/home
/Testing/demo/user
```

I have tried changing the above mounts to:

```
$app->mount('/home', new HomeControllerProvider());
$app->mount('/user', new UserControllerProvider());
```

But I just get a 404 for the following:

```
/Testing/demo/web/index.php/home
/Testing/demo/web/index.php/user
/Testing/demo/web/home
/Testing/demo/web/user
/Testing/demo/home
/Testing/demo/user
```

Project structure:

```
root
-src
--Home
--User
---UserController.php
---UserControllerProvider.php
---UserModel.php
---UserRepository.php
---UserServideProvider.php
--Application.php
-web
--.htaccess
--index.php
```

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /src
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Am I missing something here?

EDITS:

```
// UserController.php
<?php
namespace App\User;

use App\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserController
{
    protected $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->app['twig']->render('user/collection.html.twig', [
            'users' => $this->app['user.repository']->collection()
        ]);
    }
}

// UserControllerProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\User;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

class UserControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
        $controllers->get("/", 'user.controller:collection')
            ->bind('user.collection');

        return $controllers;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide code for HomeControllerProvider and UserControllerProvider, please

Comment: @Max.p Updated question with code

Answer (score 0):

You have error in defining controller in route. Try to change it to:

```
$controllers->get("/", '\\App\\User\\UserController::collection')
    ->bind('user.collection');
```

Application is not available in controller constructor. It is transmitted as argument to method that should process matched route. Try to change controller to:

```
class UserController
{
    public function collection(\Silex\Application $app)
    {
        return $app['twig']->render('user/collection.html.twig', [
            'users' => $app['user.repository']->collection()
        ]);
    }
}
```

`$app->mount(prefix, ControllerProvider)` adds all routes from `ControllerProvider` prefixed by `prefix`. Ex.:

```
class UserControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
public function connect(Application $app)
{
    $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

    // url: /user
    $controllers->get("/", '\\App\\User\\UserController::collection')
                ->bind('user.collection');

    // url: /user/111
    $controllers->get("/111", '\\App\\User\\UserController::somemethod')
                ->bind('user.route111');

    return $controllers;
}
}

$app->mount('/user', new UserControllerProvider())
```